# Codeigniter not displaying all session values in ubuntu but works fine in windows

Tags: ubuntu, codeigniter-3

i have used print_r($this->session->userdata());
browser displays only Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1521780612 )...
adminid which is stored in session is not displayed in print_r($this->session->userdata());  any solution for this will be appreciated

Comment: Are you setting the correct session config, like the path?

Comment: hi..i have used $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
$config ['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config ['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions'; ..any change required in this